# Some options are not rendering on front side USPS Shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, usps

I'm using the USPS shipping method for checkout. But some options are not rendering on the front side. You can see the admin and front sides on the screenshot.I'm using Magento2.4.2

Admin: [image]
Frontside : [image]

Comment: Could it be that USPS does not offer the method for the shipment in question?  If the USPS API doesn't return an estimate for a specific method, Magento won't display anything on the frontend. You can check by going to the USPS website and using their calculators.

Comment: @jiheison Yes that nice idea.thanks .let me check that